# Why is Main stylesheet is being applied to the WordPress front end

Tags: wordpress, stylesheet

I am in the process of developing my own theme and one of the problems I came across is my main (or any other stylesheet I add) is affecting the style of the admin dashboard.

This is how I enqueue my stylesheets:

```
function add_font_awesome(){

wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/font-    awesome.min.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_font_awesome'(), array(), '', 'all'     );
```

Am I missing something? My stylesheet is styling both the back and front end.

Comment: paste the exact code you're using, not example

Comment: Try with `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_font_awesome');`

Comment: Thanks man it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

`'add_font_awesome'()` is going to run the function instead of just telling add_action about it. You don't need the parentheses there.